# Get first array from multiples endpoints async request

Tags: php, arrays, asynchronous, promise, guzzle

I have the guzzle configured which currently uses getAsync with 4 urls promise. The return of this data comes with 2 arrays, of this format below.

My question, how can I separate into two variables, the first being just the first array? In this example, it would be the entire array of sizes 3154 and in the other variable, the entire array of sizes 10297

**Guzzle**

```
$requests = [
            getenv('apiSavingNew'), 
            getenv('apiSavingOld'),
        ];

        $promises = (function () use ($requests) {
        $client = new Client([
            'verify' => false
        ]);

        foreach ($requests as $request) {
            yield $client->getAsync($request);      
        }
        })();

        $eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
            'concurrency' => 2,
            'fulfilled' => function (Response $response) {
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
                $request = json_decode($response->getBody());
                    $firstRequest = // first array here
                    $secondRequest = // second array here
                }
            },
            'rejected' => function (RequestException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ]);

        $eachPromise->promise()->wait();
```

**Return guzzle promise**

```
array (size=3154)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[11532]
      public 'id' => string '57a64bb0-1c6a-11ec-bfd3-173b9227de8c' (length=36)
      public 'createdAt' => string '2021-09-23T12:32:40.427Z' (length=24)
      public 'data' => string '2021-09-22T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'dataFim' => string '2021-10-22T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'valor' => string '0.30120' (length=7)
      public 'serieTemporalId' => string 'a43978f1-7fd4-4550-9907-106474e64ee4' (length=36)
      public 'acumuladoAno' => null
      public 'acumulado12Meses' => null
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11539]
      public 'id' => string '57a49e00-1c6a-11ec-bfd3-173b9227de8c' (length=36)
      public 'createdAt' => string '2021-09-23T12:32:40.416Z' (length=24)
      public 'data' => string '2021-09-21T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'dataFim' => string '2021-10-21T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'valor' => string '0.30120' (length=7)
      public 'serieTemporalId' => string 'a43978f1-7fd4-4550-9907-106474e64ee4' (length=36)
      public 'acumuladoAno' => null
      public 'acumulado12Meses' => null
   more elements...

array (size=10297)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[11545]
      public 'id' => string '54f70a30-1c6a-11ec-bfd3-173b9227de8c' (length=36)
      public 'createdAt' => string '2021-09-23T12:32:35.923Z' (length=24)
      public 'data' => string '2021-09-22T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'dataFim' => string '2021-10-22T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'valor' => string '0.50000' (length=7)
      public 'serieTemporalId' => string 'ec940ca2-7da8-4a75-ae7b-d90244797b65' (length=36)
      public 'acumuladoAno' => null
      public 'acumulado12Meses' => null
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11557]
      public 'id' => string '54f3fcf0-1c6a-11ec-bfd3-173b9227de8c' (length=36)
      public 'createdAt' => string '2021-09-23T12:32:35.903Z' (length=24)
      public 'data' => string '2021-09-21T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'dataFim' => string '2021-10-21T00:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
      public 'valor' => string '0.50000' (length=7)
      public 'serieTemporalId' => string 'ec940ca2-7da8-4a75-ae7b-d90244797b65' (length=36)
      public 'acumuladoAno' => null
      public 'acumulado12Meses' => null
   more elements...
```

Comment: so you want an array of each request?

Comment: You can pass second variable $index in fulfilled and pass it along as a key name for a variable declared separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnot understood completely what your requirement is? but still I hope that this might help.
You can add the second argument to function in fulfilled as $index and add it in a separate variable for $results empty array.

```php
$results = [];
$requests = [
    getenv('apiSavingNew'), 
    getenv('apiSavingOld'),
];

$promises = (function () use ($requests) {
$client = new Client([
    'verify' => false
]);

foreach ($requests as $request) {
    yield $client->getAsync($request);      
}
})();

$eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
    'concurrency' => 2,
    'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) {
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        //$request = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $results[$index] = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        }
    },
    'rejected' => function (RequestException $e, $index) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
]);

$eachPromise->promise()->wait();
```